# Trying to call custom function in C but scanf( ) is causing an issue

Tags: c, function, scanf

Can you tell what wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int test (void)
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&i);

    return i;
}

int main (void)

{

   test();

   return 0;
}
```

This is just a simple example but for some reason main doesn't run unless I get rid of the scanf.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't run? It will be waiting for input, if that's what you mean.

Comment: just sits there doing nothing? :)  type 1<ENTER>

Comment: Also try to print something. after scanf(), give input '1' , and add statement printf(). So that you will see your program is good to go.

Comment: Nothing happens the compiler runs but nothing shows up. It just runs and runs until I forcibly close it. If I comment out the scanf(), at least "Enter a number" will show up.

Comment: I tried typing 1<ENTER> and "Enter a number:" shows up. It's like it's running backwards.

Comment: I added fflush(stdout); after the printf and it seemed to fix it. Never learned about this function in school so it's just magic to me right now.

Comment: It seems the output is buffeded and only complete lines are automatically flushed. So, something `printf("Enter a number:\n")` would flush automatically, but `printf("Enter a number: ")` requires an explicit flush.

Comment: What compiler are you using? You're not using TurboC, are you? GCC 4.4.1 behaves properly, as does Visual Studio 2010. If you are using TurboC, throw it away! Get a compiler from this century.

Answer (score 1):

Always use a `'\n'` at the end of your printf string. This makes the output buffer flush and  print the string. Add more prints in your program.
You can rewrite your program like following, and the prints will help you understand what is happening with your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int test (void)
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter a number: \n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("You just eneterd : %d\n",i);
    return i;
}

int main (void)

{
   printf("About to call test() \n");
   test();
   printf("Done calling test() \n");
   return 0;
}
```

Better get a good C programming book for understanding these basic stuff. I suggest [The C programming language](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=161QAAAAMAAJ&dq=c%20programming%20k%20and%20r&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OICgUOLAKs2pqwHCQg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must make use of fflush() or making use of a '\n' character at the end of the printf function which will eventually flush the std output buffer. For checking just make use of the printf() for printing the value of the variable just after reading the value.

Hope that helps....